# MD5 of a file from stream. Perl

Tags: perl, md5, md5-file

I need to get md5 checksum  of a file. 
But i don't have a file on a disk and i can not save it to disk.
I have only a stream (socket) from where i can read a file.

How to calculate MD5 checksum in this case and get it to be same as i would calculate it for file on a disk?

I can read chunks of any size of a stream. 
Is it possible to get correct MD5 for this case?

I need some instructions of make md5sum from sums of chunks and get same result as

```
md5sum filetohash.txt
```

I code with Perl.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to collect the data into a complete file before calculating the checksum. You may add the data in pieces to a `Digest::MD5` object, like this

```
my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new;

while ( my $chunk = read_stream() ) {
    $md5->add($chunk);
}

print $md5->hexdigest, "\n";
```

Comment: Will this method keeps all chunks in a memory together before finally calculate a hash sum?
Or it does some actions each time when you call $md5->add( ) and keeps only a result in a memory?

Comment: My question exactly.